# Docker: add a volume

Tags: docker, volume

I am running three docker instances of multichain nodes for testing purposes. Now in the Readme it says that I have to add a volume:

**Add a volume**

**:/root/.multichain**

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/Kunstmaan/docker-multichain#persisting-your-chain)

So my question is very simple: How do I add this volume? is **:/root/.multichain** a path of the host system or is it some relative path inside the docker container?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It leaves how do you map your volume up to you (namely giving you 2 persistent options). This Readme only defines what location in container should be persisted.

**Method 1 (named volume)**

```
version: '2'
services:
    masternode:
        build: ./master
        volumes:
           - namedvolume:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    slavenode:
        build: ./node
        volumes:
           - namedvolume:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    explorernode:
        build: ./explorer
        volumes:
           - namedvolume:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    # further services definitions
```

**Method 2 (direct mapping into host):**

```
version: '2'
services:
    masternode:
        build: ./master
        volumes:
           - /some/path/in/host:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    slavenode:
        build: ./node
        volumes:
           - /some/path/in/host:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    explorernode:
        build: ./explorer
        volumes:
           - /some/path/in/host:/root/.multichain
        # further definitions

    # further services definitions
```

Note that this volume should be shared across *all* the services so that all the services (nodes in this case) will have the same files and will be able to maintain the same state.

[Official docs ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes) and further reading